MAUI Edit doesn't disable spellcheck and prediction text
In my NET8 MAUI, I have this code
<Entry ...
       IsSpellCheckEnabled="False"
       IsTextPredictionEnabled="False"
       ... />

What I want to disable is the spell check and the prediction text for this Edit. The result is

the result is that the spell check and the prediction text are there. How can I remove them?

It works well for my side, my environment is simulator iPhone 15 iOS 17.5

About spellcheck and prediction text, you can refer to this: Fix IsSpellCheckEnabled #15459. Try to modify it by platform code:
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ModifyEntry();
        }
 
        void ModifyEntry()
        {
            Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyCustomization", (handler, view) =>
            {
#if ANDROID
                //handler.PlatformView.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.TextFlagNoSuggestions;
                //handler.PlatformView.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.TextFlagAutoCorrect;
#elif IOS || MACCATALYST
                handler.PlatformView.SpellCheckingType = UIKit.UITextSpellCheckingType.No;
                handler.PlatformView.AutocorrectionType = UIKit.UITextAutocorrectionType.No;
#endif
            });
        }

